# a regex that matches "something|more|here" but not "something|more|here|"

Tags: regex

I am trying to work out a regex that matches the following:

```
[something|more|here]
[another|match]
[more|matches|of|any|length]
```

However, I do not want it to match:

```
[a|bad|example|]
[|another|bad|example]
[a|bad||example|again]
```

What I currently have is:

```
/\A:\[[a-zA-Z\|]*\]/
```

This is not stringent enough since its just looking for any combination of letters and `|` signs in-between `[]`. It needs to not match `||` or a leading or trailing `|`.   What might be a good way to match on this?

Comment: didn't I do that?  The top group are samples of what it should match.  The second grouping are examples of what it shouldn't match.

Comment: Any specific language you plan to run your expression in?

Comment: What I have now is just ruby based, like this: `when /\A:\[[a-zA-Z\|]*\]/ then` ....

Comment: I've tried to make a regular expression that will follow your logic (not match || or a leading or trailing |) which are 3 total cases. The regular expression will fail unless all 3 cases are satisfied. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No look arounds required:

```
/\[[a-z]+(\|[a-z]+)*\]/i
```

See [demo](http://rubular.com/r/yeqEg5OI60)

This is variation of a fairly standard approach to matching CSV input; it takes the general form of:

```
stuff(,stuff)*
```

Comment: cleanest answer yet! Thanks, Bohemian.  What's the purpose of the `/i` at the end?

Comment: @gnychis the `i` modifier means "ignore case", so I don't have to code both upper and lower case letters in the character class, like `[a-zA-Z]`. If your flavour of regex doesn't support flags like that, you can code it into the regex by starting the regex with `(?i)`.

Comment: Even I have to admit that's pretty smart ;) +1

Answer (score 1):

I would add some look-ahead assertions for this:

```
(?!.*\|\|)(?!.*\|\])(?!.*\[\|)\[[a-zA-Z\|]+\]
```

Basically, there are 3 combinations you are trying to NOT match:

a) ||

b) [|

c) |]

and these 3 look-ahead assertions take care of that. If you're not familiar with look-ahead assertions, you have some [nice tutorials](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) you can read. I didn't get them the first time, so try reading 3-4 articles on the topic and watching some YouTube videos and you'll get it :)

Comment: thanks, that's an interesting approach.  Shouldn't the ending part of your expression `]+]` escape the final special character, like this: `]+\]` ?

Comment: My bad, yeah, it's a good thing to do, some regex engins might get confused if you don't escape it.

Answer (score 1):

As simple, as:

```
 \[([a-zA-Z]+(\|[a-zA-Z]+)*)\]
```

You can put `?` in the end, if you want to match empty brackets too:

```
 \[([a-zA-Z]+(\|[a-zA-Z]+)*)?\]
```

UPD: forgot the brackets, fixed

Answer (score 0):

### Expression

```
\[(?!\|)(?:[^|\]]|\|(?!\|))*(?<!\|)\]
```

[***Demo***](http://regex101.com/r/pP8pV2/2)

---

### Explanation

- `\[` start with `[`
- `(?!\|)` negative lookahead to make sure `[` isn't followed by `|`
- `(?:[^|\]]|\|(?!\|))*` non-capturing group repeated 0+ times:

  - `[^|\]]` anything but a `|` or a `]`
  - `|` or
  - `\|(?!\|)` a `|` not followed by a second `|`
- `(?<!\|)` negative lookbehind to make sure `]` isn't preceded by `|`
- `\]` end with `]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern:

```
\[[a-zA-Z]+(?:\|[a-zA-Z]+)*\]
```

With several regex flavors, escaping the closing square brackets is not needed, so you can write:

```
\[[a-zA-Z]+(?:\|[a-zA-Z]+)*]
```

And for a more general case that is not limited to ascii letters you can use:

```
\[[^\]|]+(?:\|[^\]|]+)*\]
```

or

```
\[[^]|]+(?:\|[^]|]+)*]
```